# python uncertainties package give me wrong uncertainty

Tags: python, uncertainty

Im calulation uncertainties with the uncertainties Package in Python. But the package is making one starnge error. When I calculate my values in my code using

```
print(ufloat(x,ux))
print(uflaot(y,uy))
print(ufloat(x,ux)/uflaot(y,uy))
```

x,y,ux,uy are values in this case

everything works fine, but when im using variables its getting messed up and the calculated value for the uncertainty is worng.

so i used this code in my document

x and y are values i calculaded before

```
print(x)
print(ufloat(1.065,0.433)) # same value as y
    
print(y)
print(ufloat(0.02123,0.00866)) # same value as y


print((x)/y)
print(ufloat(1.065,0.433)/ufloat(0.02123,0.00866))
```

and it didnt workd the output was

```
1.065(433)
1.065(433)
0.02123(866)
0.02123(866)
50.16(1.17) # false uncertainty
50.2(28.9) # true uncertaintys
```

i used a print formate here, but the usage of the formate didnt change the value

I tryd to use the code in a nother document and defined x, y like there wore in my original dokument and everything worked just fine.
ex:

```
x = ufloat(1.065,0.433)
y = ufloat(0.02123,0.00866)
print(x)
print(ufloat(1.065,0.433))
    
print(y)
print(ufloat(0.02123,0.00866))


print((x)/(y))
print(ufloat(1.065,0.433)/ufloat(0.02123,0.00866))
```

output:

```
1.1+/-0.4
1.1+/-0.4
0.021+/-0.009
0.021+/-0.009
50+/-29
50+/-29
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same problem with the uncertainties package. When you calculate an *ufloat* value from different *ufloat* values, the error propagation doesn't work as intended.

Here you can see a small example:

```
c = 3.0
x = ufloat(1, 0.5)
y = ufloat(c*x.n, c*x.s)
z = c * x

print(f"{x = }")    
print(f"{y = }")    
print(f"{z = }")    
print()
print(f"{y/x = }")
print(f"{z/x = }")
```

Output:

```
x = 1.0+/-0.5
y = 3.0+/-1.5
z = 3.0+/-1.5

y/x = 3.0+/-2.12 # expected result
z/x = 3.0+/-0    # correct nominal value, wrong uncertainty
```

I assume this is an error in the uncertainties package and is due to a problem with the variable assignment. My simple "solution" for is to create a copy of the *ufloat* variable before calculating:

```
import copy
z = c * copy.copy(x)
print(f"{z/x = }")
```

Output:

```
z/x = 3.0+/-2.12 # expected result
```

I hope this helps.